# All sounds in the app are muted after using the image picker

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

All sounds in the app are muted after using the image picker
There is no separate volume setting when loading the image picker.

Why is this?

my code

```
 @IBAction func tapRecording(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
            imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 120 // or whatever you want
            imagePicker.videoQuality = .typeMedium
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            
            player.pause()
            playButton.isHidden = false
            exampleLabel.isHidden = false
            self.navigationController?.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
        }
    }

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as! URL

        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Growth", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "GrowthSaveViewController") as? GrowthSaveViewController

        vc!.videoUrl = videoURL
        vc?.videoData = videoData

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
```